# change visbilite text in devexpress asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i need to set visibilité false in textbox and i nned to let him invisible and this the propriété of my code :

```
@Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
        f =>
        {
            f.Name = "codeclient";
            f.Text = "";
            f.Width = 300;
            f.Enabled = false;

            f.Height = 30;

            f.Properties.NullText = " choisir client";
        }).GetHtml()
```

can someone help me how to change visiblité of textbox from visible to invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(
        f =>
        {
            f.Name = "codeclient";
            f.Text = "";
            f.Width = 300;
            f.Enabled = false;
            f.ClientVisible = false;

            f.Height = 30;

            f.Properties.NullText = " choisir client";
        }).GetHtml()
```

add                 `f.ClientVisible = false;`